# Method calling and display issue

Tags: java

I am new to java and the coding is probably sloppy so please don't be harsh! Anyways, I am making a method that will set increase in turn by 1 each time I hit the end turn button.

```
public  int turns (int turn){
    int turns = 0;

if (turn == 0){
    btnYes.setEnabled(false);
    btnNo.setEnabled(false);
    btnRolldie.setEnabled(true);
    btnPurchase.setEnabled(true);
    btnMove.setEnabled(true);       
    turn++;
}
 if (turn == 1){
    btnYes.setEnabled(false);
    btnNo.setEnabled(false);
    btnRolldie.setEnabled(true);
    btnPurchase.setEnabled(true);
    btnMove.setEnabled(true);       
    turn++;
}
 if (turn == 2){
    btnYes.setEnabled(false);
    btnNo.setEnabled(false);
    btnRolldie.setEnabled(true);
    btnPurchase.setEnabled(true);
    btnMove.setEnabled(true);       
    turn++;
}
 if (turn == 3){
    btnYes.setEnabled(false);
    btnNo.setEnabled(false);
    btnRolldie.setEnabled(true);
    btnPurchase.setEnabled(true);
    btnMove.setEnabled(true);       
    turn = 0;
}
return(turns);
}

private void btnEndTurnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
int turns = 0;

lblturn.setText("" +turns(turns));
```

When I run the program, the label constantly repeats 0 whenever I hit the button. I was thinking that int turns; would work, but the variable isn't initialized. I do not know if there is an error in my method, or if the initialization in the button is overriding the method.

As I said, i'm new to java so this might be the entirely wrong approach, and if it is, please give me some recommendations on how to improve this kind of structure. Thanks!

Comment: My first advice, dont have a method and a variable with the same name, e.g. `turns`. Next, you are creating an int turns, setting it to 0, making no modification to it, then returning it. It will always be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int turns = 0;` on the second line is a local variable so the value get reset every time the method is called. You need to make it as a field of a class so that it can be shared between method. And also change `turn++` to `turns++`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be having `turns++` not `turn++`